# I will set an thumbnail in the database

Tags: php, mysqli, blob, thumbnails, gdlib

I have an PHP script that add an photo in an database with some fields, this works fine. The image in my database is an BLOB. Now will i add an thumbnail of this image directly in the database too. I am do this with the GD library, but it doesn't work.

The BLOB from the thumbnail is 0b, can anyone help me with this problem? The connection with the database is done in the top_bar and works. Everything is set in the database, only the thumbnail not.

```
  <?php
        include 'top_bar.php';
    ?>

    <div id="content">
      <?php
    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] < 60000000) { //kijken of de image is verstuurd

    // Temporary file name stored on the server

    $titel = $_POST["titel"];
    $beschrijving = $_POST["beschrijving"];
    $datum = date('Y/m/d', time());
    $categorie = $_POST["categorie"];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    // Read the file
    $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $data = addslashes($data);
    fclose($fp);

  $thumb = base64_decode($data);
  $oSourceImage = imagecreatefromstring($thumb);

  $nWidth = imagesx($oSourceImage); // get original source image width
  $nHeight = imagesy($oSourceImage); // and height

  // create small thumbnail
  $nDestinationWidth = 200;
  $nDestinationHeight = 200;
  //$oDestinationImage = imagecreatetruecolor($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);
  $oDestinationImage = imagecreate($nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight);

  imagecopyresized($oDestinationImage, $oSourceImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nDestinationWidth, $nDestinationHeight, $nWidth, $nHeight); // resize the image

  ob_start(); // Start capturing stdout.
  imageJPEG($oDestinationImage); // As though output to browser.
  $sBinaryThumbnail = ob_get_contents(); // the raw jpeg image data.
  ob_end_clean(); // Dump the result so it does not screw other output.
  $sBinaryThumbnail = addslashes($sBinaryThumbnail);


    // Create the query and insert
    // into our database.
    mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO images (id, titel, beschrijving, datum, categorie, image, thumb)
                VALUES ('','$titel','$beschrijving','$datum','$categorie','$data', '$sBinaryThumbnail')");

    // Print results
    echo "<p>De image is opgeslagen in de database.</p>";

    }
    else {
    echo "<p>Je hebt nog geen image gekozen, of het bestand is te groot</p>";
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['verstuur']) && ($_FILES["bestand"]["size"] > 60000000)) {// Bericht voor als het is verstuurd maar groter is dan 60kb
      echo "het bestand is te groot, probeer het nogmaals";
      }
    ?>
    <div id="upload_form">
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post" >
    <p>Titel:</p>          <input type="text" name="titel"><br />
    <p>Beschrijving:</p>   <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="beschrijving" placeholder="Typ hier een beschrijving"></textarea><br />
    <p class="info">De volgende categorieën bestaan op deze website:
    <?php
    $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT(categorie) FROM images");//DISTINCT laat alleen unieke waardes zien
                    while($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                         echo $rij['categorie']. ", ";
                     }
    ?> <br/>U kunt deze overnemen, of een nieuwe categorie toevoegen. Dit doet u door gewoon een nieuwe categorie te typen.</p>
    <p>Categorie:</p>      <input type="text" name="categorie"><br/>
    <p>Image:</p> <input name="image" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" type="file"><br/>
    <input value="Verzenden" type="submit" id="button">
    </form>
    </div>

    <?php
        include 'left_menu.php';
    ?>
```

I have now four warning with this script, can anyone explain why I get this warnings?
The warnings are:

```
Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in *MY URL* on line 24 Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in *MY URL* on line 25  Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in *MY URL* on line 26  Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in *MY URL* on line 36
```

Comment: Explain _it doesn't work_

Comment: The BLOB from the thumb is 0b, so he sends no information to the database for the thumbnail. Somewhere in this script goes that wrong but i don't find it.

Comment: There are quite a few SQL Injection vectors.  Make sure to sanitize your $_POST variables before concatenating them into a SQL Query.

Comment: Ok i will change this, I have now placed the errors and i have update my code in the first post. The other values are set good in the database

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/imagejpeg) of the `imagejpeg()` function. The way you call it will directly output the image to the output buffer. The variable `$tn` only contains a resource identifier. You could use `ob_start()` and `ob_get_flush()` ([documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)) around the `imagejpg()` call to fetch the actual image without writing it to a file:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($tn);
$image_contents = ob_get_flush();
// Now write $image_contents to the database, instead of $tn
```

However, it would be advisable to actually write the image to the file system and store the path to it in the database. That way the image can be served as a static file, which will increase performance in all ways.

Comment: I have edit this in my script, if I download the BLOB from the thumb and open it with my texteditor I see the content of the BLOB but it's a warning: 
`Warning: imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in *MY_URL* on line 45`

In my first post I have edit the code.

Comment: That indicates that `$tn` is probably false, which in turn indicates that the `imagecreatetruecolor()` call is failing. I think it's because the given parameters are not integers, but floating point numbers. Again, please read up on the [documentation](http://php.net/imagecreatetruecolor).

Comment: I have read this documentation, I get this warning too but i can't find it out why: Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image

Comment: I have now add some new code in my first post. Now I get four warnings: `Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in *MY URL* on line 24 Warning: imagesx() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in *MY URL* on line 25 
Warning: imagesy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in *MY URL* on line 26 
Warning: imagecopyresized() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in *MY URL* on line 36`

Do you know how I can solve this problems?

Comment: There are many things wrong with your current script. What are the `addslashes()` and `base64_decode()` calls for? I will not give a full solution for your problems, as the errors you have described are simple to debug. Just use common sense and RTFM.

Comment: The base64_decode makes from the binary data an img and the addslashes function is for backslashes the predefined characters. 
I spend a lot of time on this script because I'm new to PHP, I can't find the problem. If i set this code `$nWidth = imagesx( int $thumb);` my script crashed.

Comment: 1. No, it doesn't: [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/base64_decode). 2. What predefined characters? And what are they doing in binary data? 3. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php. 4. Learn to understand what an error message is saying. Google the error message to find out.

Comment: I have solved my first problem I think, imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image in *MY URL* on line 24.

I think i must use (header('Content-type: image/jpg');) But that is not possible in my script because I have HTML before the header.

Comment: I don't understand it can you give me some sample code. Your suggestions make me more and more confused. I have the feelding that I am close to the answer but I can't find the right answers.

Comment: I have try it on some other way with a classmate of me. But it doesn't work on the ohter way, can you see what we do wrong in that case. He asked it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962042/how-can-i-display-thumbnails-from-blob-data